# Photoviewer not working intel xdk build

Tags: intel-xdk, image-viewer

How can i build image viewer using intel xdk. 
I tried 
`https://github.com/sarriaroman/photoviewer`
plugin. 
but when building it says gradle script not supporting. Similar issue when i am using crosswalk. Any help

Answer (score 0):

The XDK builder does not support plugin gradle scripts; which means you cannot include such plugins in your app. See this FAQ for details > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/faqs/cordova#gradle-build-error <